# How to get pool3 features of Inception v3 model using Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Using Tensorflow, I get a 2048 dimensional vector as the output of the pool3 layer. However, using Keras's include_top=False gives a 8,8,2048 dimensional vector. How do I get that same vector which I get using Tensorflow's pool3 output layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the `pool_3` layer in TensorBoard.

[image]

It seems that the layer Keras returns is actually the `mixed_10` layer output.

To get the 2048-D feature vector of `pool_3`, Inception v3 appends an average pooling layer.
Since it uses a 8x8 filter, this is a simple average operation over the first two axes, so we can obtain this vector with NumPy as follows:

> pooled_vector = numpy.mean(unpooled_vector, axis=(0,1))

where `pooled_vector` is the 2048-D vector and `unpooled_vector` is your 8x8x2048 vector.

Comment: Hi, it is still not the same. The dimensions match, but the values are not the same. And for some reason, all the values in the array generated by Keras is negative.

Comment: My bad, I think the values won't be same since for Inception the original weights are different than what Tensorflow released..

Comment: Hi, according to this blog, you should set pooling='avg' directly when loading the inception model: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-implement-the-frechet-inception-distance-fid-from-scratch/
``model = InceptionV3(include_top=False, pooling='avg', input_shape=(299,299,3))``

Answer (score 0):

```
encode_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet')
encode_model = Model(encode_model.input, encode_model.layers[-2].output)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.