# Why can't I use my dataset anymore after using InceptionV3?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm currently working on video-captioning (frame-sequence to natural language).
I recently started using tf.data.Dataset class instead of feed_dict argument in tensorflow.

My goal is to feed this frames to a pretrained CNN (inceptionv3), extract the feature vector and then feed it to my RNN seq2seq network.

I've got a problem of tensorflow types after mapping my Dataset with the inception model: the dataset is then totally unusable, neither via dataset.batch() or dataset.take(). I can't even make a one shot iterator !

Here is how I proceed to build my Dataset:

**Step 1**: I first extract the same number of frames for every videos. I store all of it into a numpy array. Its shape is (nb_videos, nb_frames, width, height, channels)
Note that in this dataset, every video has the same size and has 3 color channels.

**Step 2**: Then I create a tf.data.Dataset object using this big numpy array
Note that printing this dataset via python gives:

With n_videos=2; width=240; height=320; channels=3
I already don't understand what "DataAdapter" stands for
At this point; I can create a one shot iterator but using dataset.batch(1) returns:

I don't understand why "?" and not "1" shape..

**Step 3**: I use the map function on dataset to resize all the frames of all the videos to 299*299*3 (required to use InceptionV3)
At this point, I can use the data in my dataset and make a one shot iterator.

**Step 4**: I use the map function again to extract every features using InceptionV3 pretrained model.
The problem occurs at this point:
Printing the dataset gives: 
Ok looks good
However, it's now impossible to make a one shot iterator for this dataset

*Step1* :

```py
X_train_slice, Y_train = build_dataset(number_of_samples)
```

*Step 2*:

```py
X_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X_train_slice)
```

*Step 3*:

```py
def format_video(video):
    frames = tf.image.resize_images(video, (299,299))
    frames = tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input(frames)
    return frames


X_train = X_train.map(lambda video: format_video(video))
```

*Step 4*:

Inception model:

```py
image_model = tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(include_top=False,
                                                weights='imagenet')
new_input = image_model.input

hidden_layer = image_model.layers[-1].output

image_features_extract_model = tf.keras.Model(new_input, hidden_layer)
```

For the tf.reduce_mean; see [how-to-get-pool3-features-of-inception-v3-model-using-keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043282/how-to-get-pool3-features-of-inception-v3-model-using-keras) (SO)

```py
def extract_video_features(video):
    batch_features = image_features_extract_model(video)
    batch_features = tf.reduce_mean(batch_features, axis=(1, 2))
    return batch_features

X_train = X_train.map(lambda video: extract_video_features(video))
```

Creating the iterator:

```py
iterator = X_train.make_one_shot_iterator()
```

Here is the output:

```
ValueError: Failed to create a one-shot iterator for a dataset. 
`Dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()` does not support datasets that capture 
stateful objects, such as a `Variable` or `LookupTable`. In these cases, use 
`Dataset.make_initializable_iterator()`. (Original error: Cannot capture a 
stateful node (name:conv2d/kernel, type:VarHandleOp) by value.)
```

I don't really get it: it asks me to use a initializable_iterator but this kind of iterator is dedicated for placeholder. Here, I've got raw data !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the pipelines wrong.
The idea of `tf.data` is to provide **input** pipelines to a model, not to contain the model itself. What you're trying to do it fit the model as a step of the pipeline (your step 4), but, as the error shows, this won't work.

What you should do instead is build the model as you are doing and then call `model.predict` on the input data, to obtain the features you want (as computed values). If you want to add further computation, add it in the model, since the `predict` call will run the model and return the values of the output layers.

**Side note:** `image_features_extract_model = tf.keras.Model(new_input, hidden_layer)` is completely irrelevant, given the choice you made for input and output tensors: the input is `image_model`'s input and the output is `image_model`'s output, so `image_features_extract_model` is identical to `image_model`.

The final code should be:

```
X_train_slice, Y_train = build_dataset(number_of_samples)
X_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X_train_slice)

def format_video(video):
    frames = tf.image.resize_images(video, (299,299))
    frames = tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input(frames)
    return frames

X_train = X_train.map(lambda video: format_video(video))

image_model = tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(include_top=False,
                                                weights='imagenet')
bottlenecks = image_model.predict(X_train)

# Do something with your bottlenecks
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, do you mean that instead of feeding the CNN pretrained model with my data, I tried to incorporate this model inside my data (which is non-sense) ?

Comment: Not quite. What you tried to do was to incorporate the model as a stage of the pipeline, via the `map` function. As of now, pipelines are only meant as preprocessing steps to produce data that is fed to a network, you can't `map` the network on the data to obtain the output (although it does make a lot of sense to see it that way, given how keras models in TF2 are essentially functions applied on data..).

Comment: About the tf.reduce_mean operation I used to transform mixed10 into pool3 layer:
Can I incorporate this directly in the image_model or should I apply it to bottleneck (in a new dataset) ?

Comment: I'd say you can incorporate it in the model directly, but I can't remember now how to insert a normal TF op in a keras model (although I'm 100% sure there's a way)

Comment: Apparently, you can use a keras Lambda layer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715928/valueerror-output-tensors-to-a-model-must-be-the-output-of-a-tensorflow-layer

Thank you for your answers !